# Symfony 2.4 CRUD please; Controller not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, controller

I'm (almost) new to Symfony and I'm using 2.4 but I got a problem that is giving me lots of headaches. For several days I have not been able to fix this issue.

I use the app/console commands to build my base code; from entities to crud:
doctrine:generate:entity (to build the models), then code relations, etc
doctrine:generate: entities (to generate setters, getters, etc)
doctrine:schema:update --force (to update to the database all the models)
generate:doctrine:crud (to make controllers, forms, etc....)

At last, since I choose to declare the routing via annotations, I import into my bundle's routing.yml file all the controller routes like:

```
AutocondatECRBundle_controllers:
    resource: "@AutocondatECRBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
```

This, as far as I'm aware, makes available all the routes inside the generated controllers at crud generation. However, no matter what route I try to test, Symfony keeps telling me:

**FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/var/www/autocondat-ecr/src/Autocondat/ECRBundle/Controller" from "/var/www/autocondat-ecr/src/Autocondat/ECRBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml". (Class Autocondat\ECRBundle\Controller\Clasificacion_EstudioController does not exist)**

no mater what controller or route I choose to test, always fails to find the controller class, and believe me; those classes are there.

-There are no typos on names or cases
-Classes are there, controllers are there
-Routes are there and can't be loaded even using :

```
pattern: /whatever
defaults: { _controller: AutocondatECRBundle:ControllerWhatever:index }
```

This is driving me crazy.

For anyone able to help me, here is the source of all the project:
[Link to the project](https://github.com/erparom/autocondat_ecr)

NOTES:
-There are several bundles inside my project; the one I'm testing is AutocondatECRBundle.
-Security inside security.yml file has been deactivated in order to test it faster.
-Of course, database can be generated fast with the same console commands.

Thanks -A LOT- for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your class `Autocondat\ECRBundle\Controller\Clasificacion_EstudioController`

Symfony will resolve both the namespace seperator `\` and the underscore `_` to a directory seperator, using [PSR-0 autoloading standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md#underscores-in-namespaces-and-class-names) for the autoloading of classes.

That means it is expecting your class to be located in the file `src/Autocondat/ECRBundle/Controller/Clasificacion/EstudioController.php`.

Name you class to `ClasificacionEstudioController` and the file to `ClasificacionEstudioController.php`.

Comment: Absolutely right. Thanks a lot for your help. Now I'll need to change all the Templates, Controllers, Forms, Entities, etc.... in order to delete all underscores from folder names and class names. I wish there was a reference to this convention inside Symfony Controller or CRUD manual pages.